# По умолчанию вызывать функцию в определении другой функции

Tags: python, функции, параметры

Я написала функцию, которая имеет один необязательный аргумент:

```
def myfunc(a = value)
    pass
```

По задумке, если пользователь не вводит никакой аргумент, аргументу `a` должно присваиваться значение другой функции:

```
def myfunc(a = func())
    pass
```

Но так сделать не получается. Если какой-то красивый способ реализовать задумку без мам, пап и ифов?

Comment: `Но так сделать не получается` - замечательно получается: `def func(): return 123; def f2(a=func()): return a*2` ;)

Comment: Кстати, а почему именно не получается? Что пишет в выводе после запуска скрипта?

Comment: Возможно, вы хотите вместо `func()` просто `func` написать

Comment: @dIm0n и вместо значения, возвращаемого функцией, передать саму функцию? Врядли

Comment: @cauf в том то и дело, что не сказано "значение, возвращаемое функцией", а сказано "значение другой функции". В ответе nomnoms12 написано, почему возвращаемое значение в данном случае вряд ли то, что требуется

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так делать можно. **НО** инициализация значения произойдёт единожды, а не при каждом вызове функции. И если это значение будет изменяемым, Вы можете получить странное, на первый взгляд, поведение:

```py
def func():
    return ['bacon']


def myfunc(a=func()):
    a.append('Ni!')
    print(a)


myfunc(['eggs'])  # ['eggs', 'Ni!']
myfunc()          # ['bacon', 'Ni!']
myfunc()          # ['bacon', 'Ni!', 'Ni!']
myfunc()          # ['bacon', 'Ni!', 'Ni!', 'Ni!']
```

В коде выше стандартное значение является ссылкой на список, поэтому его можно изменять. Чтобы этого не происходило, изменяемое значение нужно инициализировать в теле функции:

```py
def myfunc(a=None):
    if a is None:
        a = func()  # a = ['bacon']
```

Answer (score 3):

Оно работает

```py
def func1():
    return 'ret1'

def func2(a = func1()):
    print(a)

func2('a')
func2()
```

Вывод:

```
a
ret1
```

Comment: Работает, но стоит уточнить, что func1 выполнится только один раз, а при каждом новом запуске func2 будет использоваться только это первое значение.

Comment: @Xander, а если моя функция возвращает несколько переменных? как их грамотно распаковать в параметры другой функции?

Comment: @Angelika функция не может возвращать несколько переменных, она может возвращать кортеж (`tuple`). Распаковать кортеж в позиционные аргументы можно так: `myfunc(*func())` (при вызове).